# Array not accepting full number

Tags: c++, arrays

First off, I'm new to programming so I apologise in advance if my question seems basic!

I'm trying to construct the cows and bulls game, whereby I store a random 9 number code (between 0-1) in one array and check it against another array that the user has entered. The program then outputs the correct digits in the right place as bulls, and the correct digits in the wrong place as cows.

The problem I am having is that when I enter a number to be matched with the secret code, I need to press enter after each digit in order for it to be inputted correctly. For example, when I enter the following:

010101010 is returned as 1010101010

000000001 is returned as 1

000000000 is returned as 0

As you can see, the 1's seem to be fine but the 0's are not picked up if they are the first digit.

```
Here is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void gameOne();
void gameTwo();
void gameThree();
void getthemagicnumber(int magicnoarray[], int size);
void gettheplayernumber(int usernoarray[], int size);
void checkthenumbers(int magicnoarray[], int usernoarray[], int size);

int main()
{
    int menuChoice = 0;


        cout << "    //////////////////////////\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\n"
        "   //         Welcome to bulls and cows            \\\n"
        "  //  Where everything is not quite as it seems     \\\n"
        " //               Press 1 to play me                 \\\n"
        "//           Press 2 to let me play                   \\\n"
        "\\       Press 3 to play me with a twist              //\n"
        " \\               Press 4 to exit                    //\n"
        "  \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\/////////////////////////\n" << endl;
        cin >> menuChoice;

        switch (menuChoice)     // menu select
        {
        case 1:
            gameOne();
            break;

        case 2:
            gameTwo();
            break;

        case 3:
            gameThree();
            break;

        default:
            cout << "Thanks for playing, have a great day!" << endl;
        }
}


void gameOne()
{
    int magicnoarray[9], usernoarray[9];
    int size = 9;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    getthemagicnumber(magicnoarray, size);
    gettheplayernumber(usernoarray, size);

//  checkthenumbers(magicnoarray, usernoarray, size);
//  display the results;

//  do the above until either bulls = 9 OR 
//      number of goes = 7, or whatever you want





    cout << "your guess was: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << usernoarray[i]<<" ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "my guess was:   ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        cout << magicnoarray[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

}


void getthemagicnumber(int array[],int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        array[i] = rand() %2; 
    }
};


void  gettheplayernumber(int array[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter your guess: ";
        cin >> array[i];
    }
};



void gameTwo()
{

};

void gameThree()
{

};
```

Thank you in advance for any help, it is much appreciated!

Comment: Unrelated: I'd use the parameter `size` in `getthemagicnumber` for something besides occupying space on the activation stack, since you went through the trouble of passing it and all. Regarding your problem. you need to process the input string one char at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't read the leading zeros in an integer. You have to read it as a string and then process it however you want.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, I shall investigate strings some more in that case! EDIT: I would upvote you, but it seems I can't yet, thanks again though :)